# Add settings for flexible content in ACF/Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a little image slider/carousel using ACF flexible content any layout field. Each slide is of the field type "layout". The slider is used on multiple pages along the website. I want to add a settings field for each slider. Since its a flexible content field i have no idea how. And if i add it as a global setting on i settings page it will be used by all sliders. I want it to be individual per slider.

My fields looks like this:

[image: Fields]

And when using it on a page it looks like this:

[image: On page]

So how can i add a setting that only affect that particular slider?

My code looks like this:

```
$context["heroslider"] = get_field("heroslider");

{% for slide in slides %}
    //here im doing all the rendering of the slide's flieds.
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Just add another field of your choice next to the flex field

Comment: But that will affect all the hero sliders. lets say the setting is for bg-color. if i set it to blue on slider 2 and red on slider 2, slider 2 bg-color will override. I need it to be individual.. @Hillel

Comment: It will be individual - It will be added with every new slider and only apply to it

Comment: @Hillel Like so? https://ibb.co/bKB56TJ Quite sure i tried that yesterday, but will try again. Could have been a mistake.

Comment: Nevermind. it was just me..